# Unable to retrieve my managed package zip from my package development org (developer org - devhub)

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, sfdx-error

I am trying to retrieve my managed package zip from my package development org (developer org - devhub) using the below command

> sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -u myDevHubUser -p MyPackageName -r
> ~/Desktop -w 10

Above command is resulting with the below error response on the terminal

> Error (1): INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named
> 'MyPackageName' found

So I immediately made sure that **MyPackageName** package exist on that package development org by using the below command:

> sf package list --target-dev-hub myDevHubUser

which correctly listed the **MyPackageName** Managed package

Can you please advise how to resolve this issue and retrieve this managed package zip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two different package development methodologies.

```
sf package list --target-dev-hub myDevHubUser
```

is for developing a second-generation package. 2GPs are source-driven. There is no package zip to retrieve, and no persistent packaging org. The Dev Hub owns the package artifact.

This command:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -u myDevHubUser -p MyPackageName -r ~/Desktop -w 10
```

is something you might use if you were developing a first-generation package (1GP) in a persistent packaging org and had made changes directly in your packaging org, rather than in source control. You would never run it against a Dev Hub, as a Dev Hub cannot contain a 1GP package.

I cannot tell you which command is correct to use. You need to establish what type of package you are building and where your source of truth is located.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, it is second generation managed package.

so we can't use the sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve for second generation managed package retrieval?

Comment: No, as noted above, that's for 1GP only.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed